# AngularJs cannot get route with dot in url on localhost

Tags: javascript, angularjs, route-provider

Using route provider and having this route set:

```
.when('/:name/:id', {
```

It works (enters on my route and execute the code) when I use:

```
https://localhost.myapp.com:9000/Paul/123
```

But it does not work using this url:

```
https://localhost.myapp.com:9000/Paul/123.456
```

But my id = 123.456 so I need to use the second scenario and I get error "Cannot GET ..." so I believe that the dot is the issue.

If I check the network tab it I see that the browser interprets 123.456 like a file for example `readme.txt` it thinks that the chars after the dot is the extension of the file.

Strange thing is that on production it works.

Any ideea on how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to find an answer to this issue. It was related to webpack which was present only on my localhost and not in production (this explains why I had this issue only on localhost).

I had to add this setting in webpack config file `webpack.dev.js` under `devServer` section:

```
historyApiFallback: {
    disableDotRule: true
}
```